# Problem in listening to multicast in C++ with multiple NICs

Tags: networking, c++, multicast

I am trying to write a multicast client on a machine with two NICs, and I can't make it work. I can see with a sniffer that once I start the program the NIC (eth4) start receiving the multicast datagrams, However, I can't recieve() any in my program.

When running "tshark -i eth4 -R udp.port==xxx (multicast port)"
I get:
1059.435483 y.y.y.y. (some ip) -> z.z.z.z (multicast ip, not my eth4 NIC IP) UDP Source port: kkk (some other port) Destination port: xxx (multicast port)

Searched the web for some examples/explanations, but it seems like I do what everybody else does. Any help will be appreciated. (anything to do with route/iptables/code?)

```
bool connectionManager::sendMulticastJoinRequest()
{
struct sockaddr_in localSock;
struct ip_mreqn group;

char* mc_addr_str = SystemManager::Instance()->getTCP_IP_CHT();
char* local_addr_str = SystemManager::Instance()->getlocal_IP_TOLA();
int port = SystemManager::Instance()->getTCP_Port_CHT();
/* Create a datagram socket on which to receive. */

CHT_UDP_Feed_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

if(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock < 0)
{
    perror("Opening datagram socket error");
    return false;
}
/* application to receive copies of the multicast datagrams. */
{
  int reuse = 1;
  if(setsockopt(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
  {
      perror("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error");
      close(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock);
      return false;
  }
}

/* Bind to the proper port number with the IP address */
/* specified as INADDR_ANY. */
memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
localSock.sin_port = htons(port);
localSock.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(local_addr_str); // htonl(INADDR_ANY); //
if(bind(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)))
{
    perror("Binding datagram socket error");
    close(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock);
    return false;
}

/* Join the multicast group mc_addr_str on the local local_addr_str */
/* interface. Note that this IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option must be */
/* called for each local interface over which the multicast */
/* datagrams are to be received. */

group.imr_ifindex = if_nametoindex("eth4");
if (setsockopt(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth4", 5) < 0)
    return false;
group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(mc_addr_str);
group.imr_address.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); //also tried inet_addr(local_addr_str); instead
if(setsockopt(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
{
    perror("Adding multicast group error");
    close(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock);
    return false;
}

// Read from the socket.
char databuf[1024];
int datalen = sizeof(databuf);
if(read(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock, databuf, datalen) < 0)
{
    perror("Reading datagram message error");
    close(CHT_UDP_Feed_sock);
    return false;
}
else
{
    printf("Reading datagram message...OK.\n");
    printf("The message from multicast server is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Surely this isn't all a single method? Surely you are joining the multicast group first & then receiving via a separate method that you call many times?

Comment: Duplicate question from author:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111209/problem-in-listening-to-multicast-in-c-with-multiple-nics

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, (I've not done much work with multicast), but could it be because you're binding to a specific IP address?  The socket could be only accepting packets destined for it's bound IP address and rejecting the multicast ones?

Comment: But he isn't binding to a specific IP address. He is binding to INADDR_ANY.

Comment: When I last looked at the code above it had the local_addr_str in where the INADDR_ANY is - it's obviously been edited since then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is some time ago since I didn't play with multicast. Don't you need root/admin rights to use it? did you enable them when launching your program?